# When did “have it in” become “have it out”?

Tags: etymology, phrases, word-usage

All my life, if a person wanted to do someone harm, their attitude was described as *having it in* for that person. Lately I have noticed that this has been turned around to *having it out* for a person.

When and why has this change taken place?

Comment: Perhaps coincidentally, I heard this exact problem just within the last week or two for the first time.  I thought it might be a confusion with the phrase "having it out", or engaging in a necessary conflict.

Comment: Please provide more context. Where did you find this phrase? "Having it in" **for** someone and "having it out" **with** someone mean two different things.

Comment: *Have it out* with this meaning hasn't made it to OED yet (unsurprisingly) but it's not in Urban Dictionary either. In BrE the phrase would normally be "He's got it in for X," which doesn't change well into "He's got it out for X." But perhaps the change is connected to [imaginary] hit-man contracts.

Comment: In my experience, "have it out" means to carry through on the "have it in" impulse.  Usually in something like "I had it out with Fred", meaning I had an argument with him (though it could imply fisticuffs), about an issue that had been brewing awhile.

Answer (score 3):

***[Have it in for (someone)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have%20it%20in%20for%2Chave%20it%20out%20for&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20it%20in%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20it%20out%20for%3B%2Cc0)*** meaning "to be determined to harm or criticize someone" is  a well-established expression both in BrE and AmE and its usage, according to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have%20it%20in%20for%2Chave%20it%20out%20for&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20it%20in%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20it%20out%20for%3B%2Cc0), does not appear to be waning.

***[Have it out for (someone)](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+it+out+for)*** is also used with the same meaning, but its usage doesn't   seem to be that common and I cannot  find evidence it has surpassed that of   "have it in for". Maybe its usage is increasing among younger  people. My impression is that it may be confused with a similar expression "***[have it out with (someone)](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+it+out+with)*** which has a different meaning and is by far [more commonly used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have%20it%20in%20for%2Chave%20it%20out%20for%2C%20have%20it%20out%20with%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20it%20in%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20it%20out%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20it%20out%20with%3B%2Cc0).

(The Free Dictionary)

Comment: Your second link is a great find.  (When I heard someone use that phrase that way, I mistakenly thought they were misusing the phrase.) // I don't think OP meant that the variant is overtaking the primary phrase.  Suggest you remove the part about "surpassed".